# xmlBeans dependancy in Fuse source ESB - how to resolve?

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, xmlbeans

We are trying to transform data coming into a route from java objects to XML. For this we need xmlBeans and there is a dependancy on `DataFormatResolver`.

When we try to deploy the project, the package does not start, the status shows as `GracePeriod`.

In the error log we get the following message:

```
 11:00:24,210 | ERROR | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintContainerImpl 
 | 10 -     org.apache.aries.blueprint - 0.3.1.fuse-70-097 
 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle POC-3.0 due to 
   unresolved dependencies (&(dataformat=xmlBeans)  
   (objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver))
```

We have tried to add this class in the POM file as a dependancy, but there is a duplicate class within Fuse!

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to repackage the jars to remove the duplicate classes.  We've had to do this with the Tika jar since it included many dependencies that were stale, including XmlBeans, which conflicted with our classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the camel-xmlbeans feature first.

In the Fuse ESB shell you can type

```
features:install camel-xmlbeans
```

And then after this has been installed, you can install and start your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but Claus' answer is correct and should be accepted.  As an addendum, note that you will probably want to create a <feature> (or several) for your business logic, and then make a top-level <feature> that is dependent on all.  Something like:

```
(features.xml)

...

<feature name="com.yourbusiness::Application_Name">
    ...
    <feature>camel-xmlbeans</feature>
    <feature>com.yourbusiness::feature_one</feature>
    <feature>com.yourbusiness::feature_two</feature>
    ...
</feature>

<feature name="com.yourbusiness::feature_one">
    ...
</feature>

<feature name="com.yourbusiness::feature_two">
    ...
</feature>

...
```

hope that provides some additional insight.

Cheers,
Hans